# Add .pdf to PowerPoint?

Tags: pdf, powerpoint

I'd like to add a .pdf document as an image to my PowerPoint deck.

I tried using the ph_with(value = external_img(file.path()), but that fails. The .pdf doesn't appear on the slide.

Is there another way to call ph_with() which will insert the .pdf or will I have to convert the .pdf to a bitmap format to make this work?

Comment: Normally you can't do anything with code that can't also be done manually. If you try to place a PDF as a picture in PowerPoint for Windows, you can't, because it's not a valid picture format. You can add it as an object. In PowerPoint for Mac, PDF is a valid picture format (it gets converted to an EMF internally).

Comment: Thanks, John. Earlier today I copied a .pdf to my Windows clipboard and pasted it to the PPT slide. I just now tried to "insert" it as a picture and, as you say, it can't be done. I'll need a way to convert the .pdf to a bitmap or SVG format, preferably using an R package. Do you know of one? I've been Googling but so far come up empty.